# I can't build XCode due to an error 'sharpyuv/sharpyuv.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I can't build trough simulator because I got

```
'sharpyuv/sharpyuv.h' file not found
```

my x code version is 14.1
and my react native is

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.65.1
```

here is the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IDK why but i found out the answer i knew this is weird but it works

first i clean the DerivedData then i restart my mac then i do this

I used `pod deintegrate` then `pod install` to fix this.

from this website

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/4202